# Android BLE Gatt Characteristic WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed an Android app that connects to a CC2540 BLE peripheral.

When I do a Characteristic write of type no response (WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE), I still get the callback onCharacteristicWrite at the app level. Is this behavior correct?

I understand there is probably a low level acknowledgement that occurs between the Android device and the peripheral.

But the reason I am asking is because this is causing an issue where I can only send a write once I have received this callback, which is slowing things down in the app.

Any light on this behavior would be appreciated it.

Thanks,

Comment: yeah, that doesn't sound right...  There's a write command that has no response (on any level) which means you don't have to wait for the response.  I don't know anything about the Android BLE API, though, to help you.

Answer (score 8):

I did run into the same problem when I was trying to do some performance testing and found that when I used the WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT specifically I stopped getting a response. There might be a bug with the android constants that is causing inverse behavior, but I am not quite not sure.

Comment: Really? Sounds interesting. Seems like a silly mistake to make by the Android team. What Android version is this?

Comment: This was in 4.4 or 4.4.2. I have not tried it for a while now, but I guess it might still be happening.

Answer (score 4):

you can only make 1 transfer at a time on the low level so you need a callback to tell when the stack is ready to send another command.
If you try to send several after each other without waiting for the air-interface to be ready you can seriously crash the BLE stack! This was happening a lot on earlier iOS CoreBluetooth.
If one app crashes the BLE Stack then the phone need a reset or Bluetooth must be turned off and on again to reset the stack.
The callback just tells you that the stack has send a request over the air-interface, not that it was acknowledged by the recipient. For that you would use the other api which will make the BLE Stack re-transmit several times (depending on how the connection parameters has been negotiated).

It's stated clearly in the BLE specification that only 1 transfer can be made at a time.

If you just bang the API with write requ

Comment: This is not true. In the BLE core spec you have Write Request and Write Command. Write Request will give you a response back telling you the write was successful. A Write Command gets no response and you can send as many of them as you like. The receiving GATT server does not guarantee the write (it's unreliable), but nothing should crash and the link should be just fine. If the iOS stack used to crash I guess that has been fixed now. That had to be a bug and does not reflect what you should and should not do.

Comment: @VegarWesterlund I'm seeing this behavior for multiple reads. I have to force my reads to be synchronous - wait for "on read" callback before issuing another "read". Are you saying this is bogus? I don't see a Command vs Request on the reading side of the interaction.

Comment: @Splash: I don't know if your using Android, iOS or some other stack, but here's how it's supposed to work. At the low(est) level there is an HCI interface. It has a number of data buffers (say six). You can then queue up at most six outgoing packets (say read request). The higher levels should either keep track of the available buffers or handle the Data Buffer Overflow event. Either way the API you have access to should take care of this for you and either block the read request or give an error message. Hammering the API should not make it crash or even misbehave.

Comment: @VegarWesterlund Yes, one would expect a properly designed API to handle that kind of thing for you. Android's Bluetooth API, however, does not, and I am working with API level 26. The behavior I am seeing is exactly what henrik describes.